# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: isfinite(coefficient)' crash

Tags: iphone, crash

I get this crash report of which I cannot get the line in my code by symbolicating:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
'Invalid parameter not satisfying: isfinite(coefficient)'
```

I searched my code for both function isfinite and variable coefficient and of course I found none. The crash was attributed to System 7.1.2 on iPhone6,1

What might have determined it?

Comment: The problem is exactly that I cannot get the code snippet producing the error. The log comes from QuincyKit and the symbolication fails like if the error were produced outside my code altogether.

Comment: I have the same crash in BugSense/Mint. No idea where it's coming from. Also from 7.1.2.

Comment: any update for this issue? i am also having the same issue

Comment: I think I have fixed it, but it was so long ago I forgot what was the issue. Sorry for that.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. If anybody have solution for this please share me like or solution. I am trying this since from two days still not able to solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and discovered it was an issue with auto layout not being able to satisfy constraints.

For me this was solved by removing proportional size constraints which couldn't be satisfied when their corresponding view was hidden.

If you need to keep the constraints, consider to lower their priority.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Could you show how to remove the proportional size constraints and/or how to lower their priority?

Comment: It is indeed an autolayout issue, but in my case, I was adding `leftAnchor` and `topAnchor` constraints which weren't necessary. Removing them resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and similar to Timothy it turned out to be an auto layout constraint issue, but for a different reason.  It took hours but I tracked it down to the `CGRectInset()` function appears to have a bug in the latest iOS 16.2.  This app was working before iOS 16.2 and now it is getting this exception at startup, with no app changes in between.  *The exception now makes sense, the UI code is checking to see if a value isfinite and it is not, it's infinite.*

In my case calling `insetBy(dx: 5, dy: 0)` (in Swift) caused the x and y fields to get infinite values when the original x/y are 0.  I think this was a bug introduced in iOS 16.2.  I'll file a bug report with Apple and see what they say.

[image]
My code was calling `insetBy(dx: 5, dy: 0)` and the result was `+Inf`.  Doesn't make sense and documentation on that function doesn't mention this possibility.

[image]